# Replacing end of word with something else

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have this:

```
echo "walking ringer talking"
```

How do I use sed to achieve the following output?

```
walked ringer talked
```

I've tried several ways, but can't get it to work. The following commands are what I've tried.

```
echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing/ed/g'
```

This outputs `walked reder talked`.

```
echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing$/ed/g'
```

This outputs `walking ringer talked`.

```
echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/^ing/ed/g;s/ing$/ed/g'
```

This outputs `walking ringer talked`.

I'm trying to get this done in a bash script.

Comment: If you only want to replace the first occurence, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: Why don't you replace `king` with `ked` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add space  `'s/ing /ed /g;` in your third test;

```
#echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/^ing/ed/g;s/ing$/ed/g' 
echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing /ed /g;s/ing$/ed/g'
```

eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing /ed/g;s/ing$/ed/g' 
walked ringer talked
```

Answer (score 2):

To match either a space or newline at the end of the pattern, you can use:

```
sed -E 's/ing( |$)/ed\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk will split the string in three pieces and apply substitution to the desired elements. Then `print $0` will return the entire (new) string.

```
echo $s | awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=a[3]}{for(x in a)gsub("ing","ed",$x); print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "end of word" marker:

```
$ echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing\>/ed/g'
walked ringer talked
```

`\>` matches where you have word characters on the left and non-word characters on the right.

Or, less specific, with a word boundary:

```
$ echo "walking ringer talking" | sed 's/ing\b/ed/g'
walked ringer talked
```

`\b` matches any word boundary, but if it follows word characters, it's equivalent to `\>`.